# htaccess redirect with L-flag?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want a user, that tries to reach somedomain.com/somethingold (with or without www) to be redirected to www.somedomain.com/somethingnew. Normally I'd just use a simple Redirect rule, but I also don't want any other following rules to be applied. I guess for that we have the L-flag, but that doesn't work with a simple Redirect, but only with RewriteRule. Is that correct? So how would I write it then?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can always change your redirects to rewrites: 
`RewriteRule new.htm$ http://www.example.com/old.htm [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works.